# Subversion plug-in error in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, installation, jenkins-plugins

I download and install a `jenkins.msi` for Windows installation.

I open the URL `localhost:8080` to open Jenkins.

The UI is getting started, when long time ago I comeback to look it all the plug-in is ok but only the Subversion plug-in had failed.

I don't know how to fit it, someone tell me that close it and open it again try but failed:

[image]

**UPDATE**

From `jenkins.err.log`:

> Failed to install Subversion Plug-in hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to download from http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/subversion/2.6/subversion.hpi (redirected to: http://ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp/software/jenkins/plugins/subversion/2.6/subversion.hpi)

Comment: Have a look into `jenkins.[n.]out.log` and `jenkins.[n.]err.log` in your Jenkins installation folder.

Comment: Failed to install Subversion Plug-in
hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to download from http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/subversion/2.6/subversion.hpi (redirected to: http://ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp/software/jenkins/plugins/subversion/2.6/subversion.hpi)

Comment: The download via browser works with both URLs here. What happens if you try downloading them in a browser on your Jenkins machine?

Comment: jenkins was build in my machine the the others plug download is ok only the svn plug can not be download .

Comment: Once again: What happens if you try downloading them in a browser on your Jenkins machine? (not in Jenkins' Web UI, but directly, by entering the URLs in your browser's address bar)

Comment: thanks it's ok just the web ui loading slowing,after than it's ok .thanks a lot